# Why can't I draw a rectangle in Phaser 3 JS?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Using Javascript with Phaser 3, I'm trying to draw a rectangle to the canvas. Drawing a circle using the same method isn't a problem, but rectangles won't work. How do you draw a rectangle? I've demonstrated my current attempts to do so below. The circle shows but the rectangle doesn't.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Colour Circles</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>


function create() {
    const rect = this.add.rectangle(200, 200, 30, 30, 0x4c7df3);
    const circle = this.add.circle(200, 200, 30, 0x4c7df3);

}

const config = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  parent: 'phaser-game',
  backgroundColor: 0xffc836,
  width: 440,
  height: 550,
  scene: {
    create,
  }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Further: a rectangle will show with those code, but only so long as the rest of the code is there. If any of those lines are missing, the 'this.add.rectangle' command fails to work.

```
function create ()
{
  rect1 = this.add.rectangle(200, 475, 440, 75, 0x37c3be);

  const spacing = 4 / gameState.palette.length;
  const translation = spacing / 2;

  for (let i = 0; i < gameState.palette.length; i++) {
    let color = gameState.palette[i];
    let paletteCircle = this.add.circle(translation + spacing * i, 515, 22, color);


  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this line causes a problem

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.15.1/dist/phaser-arcade-physics.min.js"></script>
```

you should add `phaser.js` or `phaser.min.js` to your page
try this one It's the latest version.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.23.0/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

More details can be found on the phaser [docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Game.html)
You can Find many useful examples [here](https://phaser.io/examples/v3)

Comment: Adding this didn't make any difference. Are there any other problems you could see?

Comment: No, the rectangle just doesn't show up. Everything else works fine.

Comment: I forgot to write `https` it will work now. and the rectangle is hidden behind the circle, change the circle to `this.add.circle(300, 200, 30, 0x4c7df3);`